# Ошибка при запуске образа docker на ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker

Установлена ubuntu 20.04 WSL2.
При запуске команды `sudo docker run -p 5000:5000 -it fls`
Появляется ошибка:
`(HTTP code 400) unexpected - OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown` 
Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

MAINTAINER Mike Abramov "test@test.ru"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python3.8 python3.8-dev python3-pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В 20.03 пакеты с питоном версий 3.x, как-то `python3.8`, содержат только исполняемый файл `python3`. Исполняемый файл `python` - это часть пакетов версии 2.х, а вы его не устанавливали.

Чтобы исправить, укажите в `ENTRYPOINT` `python3`.